# SQL LEFT JOIN to many categories

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Suppose the following easy [scenario](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=6e0a5295ca39de22960935642da97690), where a product row gets connected to one primary category, subcategory, and sub-subcategory.

```
DECLARE @PRODUCTS TABLE (ID int, DESCRIPTION varchar(50), CAT varchar(30), SUBCAT varchar(30), SUBSUBCAT varchar(30));

INSERT @PRODUCTS (ID, DESCRIPTION, CAT, SUBCAT, SUBSUBCAT) VALUES
(1, 'NIKE MILLENIUM', '1', '10', '100'),
(2, 'NIKE CORTEZ', '1', '12', '104'),
(3, 'ADIDAS PANTS', '2', '27', '238'),
(4, 'PUMA REVOLUTION 5', '3', '35', '374'),
(5, 'SALOMON SHELTER CS', '4', '15', '135'),
(6, 'NIKE EBERNON LOW', '2', '14', '157');

DECLARE @CATS TABLE (ID int, DESCR varchar(100));

INSERT @CATS (ID, DESCR) VALUES
(1, 'MEN'),
(2, 'WOMEN'),
(3, 'UNISEX'),
(4, 'KIDS'),
(5, 'TEENS'),
(6, 'BACK TO SCHOOL');

DECLARE @SUBCATS TABLE (ID int, DESCR varchar(100));

INSERT @SUBCATS (ID, DESCR) VALUES
(10, 'FOOTWEAR'),
(12, 'OUTERWEAR'),
(14, 'SWIMWEAR'),
(15, 'HOODIES'),
(27, 'CLOTHING'),
(35, 'SPORTS');

DECLARE @SUBSUBCATS TABLE (ID int, DESCR varchar(100));

INSERT @SUBSUBCATS (ID, DESCR) VALUES
(100, 'RUNNING'),
(104, 'ZIP TOPS'),
(135, 'FLEECE'),
(157, 'BIKINIS'),
(238, 'PANTS'),
(374, 'JOGGERS');


SELECT prod.ID,
    prod.DESCRIPTION,
    CONCAT(cat1.DESCR, ' > ', cat2.DESCR, ' > ', cat3.DESCR) AS CATEGORIES
FROM @PRODUCTS AS prod
LEFT JOIN @CATS AS cat1 ON cat1.ID = prod.CAT
LEFT JOIN @SUBCATS AS cat2 ON cat2.ID = prod.SUBCAT
LEFT JOIN @SUBSUBCATS AS cat3 ON cat3.ID = prod.SUBSUBCAT;
```

Now suppose that the foreign keys on `@PRODUCTS` table aren't just indices to their respective tables. They are comma-separated indices to more than one categories, subcategories, and sub-subcategories like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3ea6d7bd3621d8914588a5201bb8f05d).

```
DECLARE @PRODUCTS TABLE (ID int, DESCRIPTION varchar(50), CAT varchar(30), SUBCAT varchar(30), SUBSUBCAT varchar(30));

INSERT @PRODUCTS (ID, DESCRIPTION, CAT, SUBCAT, SUBSUBCAT) VALUES
(1, 'NIKE MILLENIUM', '1, 2', '10, 12', '100, 135'),
(2, 'NIKE CORTEZ', '1, 5', '12, 15', '104, 374'),
(3, 'ADIDAS PANTS', '2, 6', '27, 35', '238, 374');

DECLARE @CATS TABLE (ID int, DESCR varchar(100));

INSERT @CATS (ID, DESCR) VALUES
(1, 'MEN'),
(2, 'WOMEN'),
(3, 'UNISEX'),
(4, 'KIDS'),
(5, 'TEENS'),
(6, 'BACK TO SCHOOL');

DECLARE @SUBCATS TABLE (ID int, DESCR varchar(100));

INSERT @SUBCATS (ID, DESCR) VALUES
(10, 'FOOTWEAR'),
(12, 'OUTERWEAR'),
(14, 'SWIMWEAR'),
(15, 'HOODIES'),
(27, 'CLOTHING'),
(35, 'SPORTS');

DECLARE @SUBSUBCATS TABLE (ID int, DESCR varchar(100));

INSERT @SUBSUBCATS (ID, DESCR) VALUES
(100, 'RUNNING'),
(104, 'ZIP TOPS'),
(135, 'FLEECE'),
(157, 'BIKINIS'),
(238, 'PANTS'),
(374, 'JOGGERS');


SELECT prod.ID,
    prod.DESCRIPTION
    --CONCAT(cat1.DESCR, ' > ', cat2.DESCR, ' > ', cat3.DESCR) AS CATEGORIES
FROM @PRODUCTS AS prod
--LEFT JOIN @CATS AS cat1 ON cat1.ID = prod.CAT
--LEFT JOIN @SUBCATS AS cat2 ON cat2.ID = prod.SUBCAT
--LEFT JOIN @SUBSUBCATS AS cat3 ON cat3.ID = prod.SUBSUBCAT;
```

In this case I want to achieve the following:

1. Be able to retrieve the respective names of the cats, subcats, sub-subcats, ie. for cats '1, 2' be able to retrieve their names (I tried `LEFT JOIN @CATS AS cat1 ON cat1.ID IN prod.CAT` but it doesn't work)
2. Create triplets of the corresponding cats, subcats, sub-subcats, ie. for

- cats '1, 2'
- subcats '12, 17'
- sub-subcats '239, 372'

(after retrieving the appropriate names) create pipe-separated category *routes* like `name of cat 1` > `name of subcat 12` > `name of sub-subcat 239` | `name of cat 2` > `name of subcat 17` > `name of sub-subcat 372`

So, for a row like `(1, 'NIKE MILLENIUM', '1, 2', '10, 12', '100, 135'),`

I would like to get the following result

| ID | DESCRIPTION | CATEGORIES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NIKE MILLENIUM | MEN > FOOTWEAR > RUNNING @ WOMEN > OUTERWEAR > FLEECE (I had to use @ as the delimiter of the two triplets because pipe messed with the table's columns) |

In case the user stupidly stores more cat IDs than subcat IDs, or sub-subcat IDs, the query should just match the ones that have a corresponding position match, ie for

- cats '1, 2'
- subcats '12'
- sub-subcats '239, 372'

it should just create one triplet, like `name of 1` > `name of 12` > `name of 239`

Comment: Hello! For 1. I copied the code of the fiddles in my question - I suppose that was what you meant, right? For 2. and 3. I think my question already covers those. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Give me one moment, and I'll do it! :)

Comment: The obvious solution is to fix your design... this is a terrible way to store your relationships and will plague you until you fix it.

Comment: And what have you actually tried? A select isn't really an attempt. You're going to have to do something like a string split following by a join followed by a concatenation.

Comment: No, no! This is not something I have control over! The app uses three int fields for storing the primary cat > subcat > sub-subcat indices, and three more varchar fields for storing comma-separated indices of cats, subcats, and sub-subcats...

Comment: As I said, thats terrible, push back and tell the app designed to do it properly. But if not have a go and see how you get on.

Comment: That delimited mess you have been handed violates 1NF and is a serious PITA to work with. Even worse that shoved a space in after the delimiter. Ugh!!! You are going to need to utilize string_split here since you are stuck with this design.

Comment: What space? The spaces around '>'? Ie, for the primary triplets, where in each field only one index is stored, I do it like this: `CONCAT(cat1.DESCR, ' > ', cat2.DESCR, ' > ', cat3.DESCR) AS CATEGORIES`... The problem arouse in the secondary cats, where I have more indices per field... Is this totally not doable in SQL Dale?

Comment: First that was Sean who said that. I also gave you a starting tip "You're going to have to do something like a string split following by a join followed by a concatenation."

Comment: Thanks for the tip, sorry for confusing you with Sean, I didn't realize the different username! So I'll try some things and get back to report my achievements! :D

Comment: By space I  mean '100, 135'. Notice the space after the comma? Although since you are ending up with a conversion to int the leading space won't cause any issue.

Comment: Will there always be the same number of cats, subcats, and subsubcats (like 2 of each or 3 of each).  Are they always related by ordinal position?  In your example, why only 1-12-239 and 2-17-372?  Why not also 1-12-372, 2-12-239, 2-12-372, etc?

Comment: Looks like I missed the last bit of the question.  Ordinal position it is.  Fire your data architect.

Comment: @dougp those are secondary categories (there are three other fields that determine the primary CAT > SUBCAT > SUB-SUBCAT categorization of the product). So for the secondary categorization, there is no fixed number. It would depend on the product. There are 3 fields, each one for cat, subcat, and sub-subcat indices.

Comment: Hehe, I'm not related to the development of the app... I'm only the person who tries to build a bridge between this desktop merchant app, and an e-shop that I'm building for it, that will be pulling data from the app!

Comment: @DaleK it gets better and better... I don't even have available `STRING_SPLIT`... They're running SQL Server 2014! :(

Comment: There are loads of alternatives available.

Comment: Apart from the delimited problem, there is another denormalization issue: the product should just relate to a sub-sub-cat, not to a category or sub-cat. Otherwise it would be theoretically possible to associate it with a sub-category, where the associated category is not the parent of it

Comment: @Charlieface I know there are so many traps and dangers in this implementation, but it is what it is... That's how they implemented it to the customer, and I've warned him that he should be extra cautious when selecting the parent-child cat(s)/subcat(s)/subsubcat(s) hierarchy... Now I have to retrieve that data in the way I described above in order to import the data in the website I'm building for him. dougp's implementation is **exactly** what I need, except for that it's compatible to SQL Server 2016+

Comment: Given that you are still on sql server 2014 and not able to reap many of the benefits of a newer version all hope is not lost. A good friend Eirikur Eiriksson wrote an amazing extension to another popular splitter by Jeff Moden. His newer version will work just fine on 2014. I am currently using is on a 2012 instance and it is amazing. You can read about his splitter function here. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2 It is a crazy fast splitter that ensures ordinal position of each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally separate answer because of the change to older technology.  I think my original answer is still good for folks using current SQL Server versions, so I don't want to remove it.

I don't remember where I got the function.  When I found it today it was named split_delimiter.  I changed the name, added some comments, and incorporated the ability to have a delimiter that is more than one character long.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_split_string](@delimited_string VARCHAR(8000), @delimiter varchar(10))
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
WITH cte10(num) AS (    --  10 rows
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)                         
, cte100(num) AS (  --  100 rows
    SELECT 1 
    FROM   cte10 t1, cte10 t2
)
, cte10000(num) AS (    --  10000 rows
    SELECT 1 
    FROM   cte100 t1, cte100 t2
)
, cte1(num) AS (    --  1 row per character
    SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@delimited_string), 0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
    FROM   cte10000
)
, cte2(num) AS (    --  locations of strings
    SELECT  1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.num + len(replace(@delimiter, ' ', '_'))
    FROM   cte1 t
    WHERE  SUBSTRING(@delimited_string, t.num, len(replace(@delimiter, ' ', '_'))) = @delimiter
)
, cte3(num, [len]) AS (
    SELECT t.num
         , ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @delimited_string, t.num), 0) - t.num, 8000)
    FROM  cte2 t
)

SELECT [Key]   = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.num)
     , [Value] = SUBSTRING(@delimited_string, t.num, t.[len])
FROM cte3 t;
GO



DECLARE @PRODUCTS TABLE (ID int, DESCRIPTION varchar(50), CAT varchar(30), SUBCAT varchar(30), SUBSUBCAT varchar(30));

INSERT @PRODUCTS (ID, DESCRIPTION, CAT, SUBCAT, SUBSUBCAT) VALUES
(1, 'NIKE MILLENIUM', '1, 2', '10, 12', '100, 135'),
(2, 'NIKE CORTEZ', '1, 5', '12, 15', '104, 374'),
(3, 'ADIDAS PANTS', '2, 6, 1', '27, 35, 10', '238, 374, 100'),
(4, 'JOE THE PLUMBER JEANS', '1, 5', '27', '238, 374');

DECLARE @CATS TABLE (ID int, DESCR varchar(100));

INSERT @CATS (ID, DESCR) VALUES
(1, 'MEN'),
(2, 'WOMEN'),
(3, 'UNISEX'),
(4, 'KIDS'),
(5, 'TEENS'),
(6, 'BACK TO SCHOOL');

DECLARE @SUBCATS TABLE (ID int, DESCR varchar(100));

INSERT @SUBCATS (ID, DESCR) VALUES
(10, 'FOOTWEAR'),
(12, 'OUTERWEAR'),
(14, 'SWIMWEAR'),
(15, 'HOODIES'),
(27, 'CLOTHING'),
(35, 'SPORTS');

DECLARE @SUBSUBCATS TABLE (ID int, DESCR varchar(100));

INSERT @SUBSUBCATS (ID, DESCR) VALUES
(100, 'RUNNING'),
(104, 'ZIP TOPS'),
(135, 'FLEECE'),
(157, 'BIKINIS'),
(238, 'PANTS'),
(374, 'JOGGERS');

;
with prod as (
    SELECT p.ID,
        p.DESCRIPTION
        , c.value as CatId
        , c.[key] as CatKey
        , sc.value as SubCatId
        , sc.[key] as SubCatKey
        , ssc.value as SubSubCatId
        , ssc.[key] as SubSubCatKey
    FROM @PRODUCTS p
      cross apply dbo.udf_split_string(cat, ', ') c
      cross apply dbo.udf_split_string(subcat, ', ') sc
      cross apply dbo.udf_split_string(subsubcat, ', ') ssc
    where c.[key] = sc.[key]
      and c.[key] = ssc.[key]
)
, a as (
    select p.ID
    , p.DESCRIPTION
    , c.DESCR + ' > ' + sc.DESCR + ' > ' + ssc.DESCR as CATEGORIES
    , p.CatKey
    from prod p
      inner join @CATS c on c.ID = p.CatId
      inner join @SUBCATS sc on sc.ID = p.SubCatId
      inner join @SUBSUBCATS ssc on ssc.ID = p.SubSubCatId
)

select DISTINCT ID
, DESCRIPTION
, replace(STUFF((SELECT distinct ' | ' + a2.CATEGORIES
            from a a2
            where a.ID = a2.ID
            FOR XML PATH(''))
        ,1,2,''), '&gt;', '>') CATEGORIES
from a
```

Comment: This works like a charm dougp, thank you so very much for your dedication to helping me even though the requirements of my case were very specific and tough to deal with.

Comment: dougp can you please explain to me the STUFF() part of the query? Why do we use it? This is not quite clear to me! Can't we just use a CONCAT() to add the rest of the hierarchies?

Answer (score 2):

`STRING_SPLIT()` does not promise to return the values in a specific order, so it won't work in this case as ordinal position matters.

Use `OPENJSON()` split the string into separate rows to ensure the values are returned in the same order.
`OPENJSON()` also returns a `key` field, so you can join on the row number within each grouping.  You'll want an `INNER JOIN` since your requirement is that all values in that "column" must exist.
Use `STUFF()` to assemble the various cat>subcat>subsubcat values.

```
DECLARE @PRODUCTS TABLE (ID int, DESCRIPTION varchar(50), CAT varchar(30), SUBCAT varchar(30), SUBSUBCAT varchar(30));

INSERT @PRODUCTS (ID, DESCRIPTION, CAT, SUBCAT, SUBSUBCAT) VALUES
(1, 'NIKE MILLENIUM', '1, 2', '10, 12', '100, 135'),
(2, 'NIKE CORTEZ', '1, 5', '12, 15', '104, 374'),
(3, 'ADIDAS PANTS', '2, 6, 1', '27, 35, 10', '238, 374, 100'),
(4, 'JOE THE PLUMBER JEANS', '1, 5', '27', '238, 374');

DECLARE @CATS TABLE (ID int, DESCR varchar(100));

INSERT @CATS (ID, DESCR) VALUES
(1, 'MEN'),
(2, 'WOMEN'),
(3, 'UNISEX'),
(4, 'KIDS'),
(5, 'TEENS'),
(6, 'BACK TO SCHOOL');

DECLARE @SUBCATS TABLE (ID int, DESCR varchar(100));

INSERT @SUBCATS (ID, DESCR) VALUES
(10, 'FOOTWEAR'),
(12, 'OUTERWEAR'),
(14, 'SWIMWEAR'),
(15, 'HOODIES'),
(27, 'CLOTHING'),
(35, 'SPORTS');

DECLARE @SUBSUBCATS TABLE (ID int, DESCR varchar(100));

INSERT @SUBSUBCATS (ID, DESCR) VALUES
(100, 'RUNNING'),
(104, 'ZIP TOPS'),
(135, 'FLEECE'),
(157, 'BIKINIS'),
(238, 'PANTS'),
(374, 'JOGGERS');

;
with prod as (
    SELECT p.ID,
        p.DESCRIPTION
        --CONCAT(cat1.DESCR, ' > ', cat2.DESCR, ' > ', cat3.DESCR) AS CATEGORIES
        , c.value as CatId
        , c.[key] as CatKey
        , sc.value as SubCatId
        , sc.[key] as SubCatKey
        , ssc.value as SubSubCatId
        , ssc.[key] as SubSubCatKey
    FROM @PRODUCTS p
      cross apply OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(cat, ', ', '","'), '"]')) c
      cross apply OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(subcat, ', ', '","'), '"]')) sc
      cross apply OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(subsubcat, ', ', '","'), '"]')) ssc
    where c.[key] = sc.[key]
      and c.[key] = ssc.[key]
)
, a as (
    select p.ID
    , p.DESCRIPTION
    , c.DESCR + ' > ' + sc.DESCR + ' > ' + ssc.DESCR as CATEGORIES
    , p.CatKey
    from prod p
      inner join @CATS c on c.ID = p.CatId
      inner join @SUBCATS sc on sc.ID = p.SubCatId
      inner join @SUBSUBCATS ssc on ssc.ID = p.SubSubCatId
)

select DISTINCT ID
, DESCRIPTION
, replace(STUFF((SELECT distinct ' | ' + a2.CATEGORIES
            from a a2
            where a.ID = a2.ID
            FOR XML PATH(''))
        ,1,2,''), '&gt;', '>') CATEGORIES
from a
```

Comment: OMG, this is brilliant! And so advanced for my SQL Server skills, but I'd be able to adapt it to my case if it was compatible with SQL Server 2014! It even takes care of 'orphaned' superfluous indices that might exist for either a cat, subcat or sub-subcat... :(

Comment: dougp there is no easy solution - or not at all - to my problem for SQL Server 2014, is there?

Comment: You would need to write a user-defined function to replace what `OPENJSON(CONCAT())` is doing.  I don't think it will be that difficult, especially if you have a limited number of values in the string.  Did you say there is a maximum of 3 IDs per string?  Do you have permission to make a UDF?

Comment: The `split` function Carlos mentions looks like a good start, but I think you'll need to add a key to join by column number.

Answer (score 1):

Well that should do work, i changed your character ">" for "-" just for see the data more simple.

the design of your tables is not perfect but the first try almost never is.

```
select mainp.ID, mainp.DESCRIPTION, stuff(ppaths.metapaths, len(ppaths.metapaths),1,'') metalinks
from @PRODUCTS mainp
cross apply(
select
(select 
  c.DESCR + '-' + sc.DESCR + '-' + sbc.DESCR + '|'
from @PRODUCTS p    
    cross apply (select row_number() over(order by Value) id, Value from split(p.CAT, ','))cat_ids
    inner join @cats c on c.ID = cat_ids.Value
    cross apply (select row_number() over(order by Value) id, Value from split(p.SUBCAT, ','))subcat_ids
    inner join @SUBCATS sc on sc.ID = subcat_ids.Value
    and subcat_ids.id = subcat_ids.id
    cross apply (select row_number() over(order by Value) id, Value  from split(p.SUBSUBCAT, ','))subsubcat_ids
    inner join @SUBSUBCATS sbc on sbc.ID = subsubcat_ids.Value
    and subsubcat_ids.id = subcat_ids.id
where p.id = mainp.ID
for xml path('')) metapaths
) ppaths
```

the link for split function
https://desarrolladores.me/2014/03/sql-server-funcion-split-para-dividir-un-string/

Comment: It turns out it doesn't work well afterall... Unfortunately it creates all possible combinations of cat/subcat/subsubcat... Whereas it's needed to match only cats/subcats/subsubcats with the same ordinal position... That means that for cat [1,2,3], subcat [10,20,30] and subsubcat [100,200,300] it should only create 3 hierarchies, which should be 1 > 10 > 100, 2 > 20 > 200 and 3 > 30 > 300

Comment: @FayeD. just add sequence number and join, simple.

Comment: Carlos, can you please elaborate on this a little?